# Is my new-to-me used suspension fork a MY2000 Manitou Mars Elite Hyperlite?

Tags: fork, suspension, 26-inch

I just got a new-to-me used fork from circa 2000. It's supposed to be a 26" 1 1/8th threadless Manitou Mars Elite fork with 80mm travel.  I'd like to source spare parts and repair/service instructions -- do I have it correctly identified as a MY2000 Manitou Mars Elite Hyperlite? I've uploaded photos, in particular one with a date code stamp on the "bridge" that shows "00" surrounded by 12 wedges, 11 of which have raised dots. This suggests to me a manufacturing date of 11/2000, which may or may not be MY2000.  Serial number is 300169715, but I've been unable to find a decoder that gives date of manufacture or model year from that, and Hayes(Manitou) hasn't yet returned my call.
Q: Is this a MY2000 Manitou Mars Elite 26" 1 1/8 threadless 80mm fork? MY2001? Some other variety of Mars fork?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hayes tech support recently returned my call on this, and although they don't have access to serial number records that far back, they did confirm that the 11-00 manufacturing date stamped in the arch almost certainly means it's MY 2001. They also sent me the tech manual -- I was impressed with Hayes' helpfulness!

Comment: Nice work!  Thank you for coming back and closing the loop.